# one to one or zero association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Model I

```
class TimeLog < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :custom_time_fields,  :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Model II

```
class CustomTimeFields <  ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :time_log
end
```

above design in terms of database will be

timelogs table + custom_time_field_id(foreign key)

custom_time_fields

So when i delete *timelog* entry its associated 'custom_time_field' will be auto deleted by rails

But i want database design like following

Table I:

time_logs

Table II

custom_time_fields (having time_log_id as foreign key)

Table I will have ***Zero or one*** association of Table II

How can i represent above database design in Rails models, so that when i delete time_log, associated custom_time_field entry is auto deleted.

Comment: what's the problem with your current code?

Comment: i just need to change the design

Comment: i don't see what's wrong about the current one

Comment: yes. i guess models are correct. i dont need to change them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to switch the `has_one` and `belongs_to` relations of your models to change the table containing the foreign key (the model with the relation `belongs_to` is the one holding the foreign key). Do not forget to adapt your migrations according to the change (to declare the `time_log_id` column).

I think the "zero or one" relation you're looking for is the `has_one` relation. This relation is not mandatory (unless you add a [validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validations-overview) to it).

Comment: but then in that case, will custom_time_field entry be auto deleted when time_entry is deleted? because time_entry doesnot know about custom_time_field

Comment: yes, the `dependent` option is also available for `belongs_to` relation. Rails will handle the deletion of the related object for you. See guide for options: 4.1.2  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs_to-association-reference

Comment: oh! got it. thnx for the explanation

Comment: as u said, the model with the relation belongs_to is the one holding the foreign key. then in that case i dont need to switch the relations the models that i have written in the post are correct. i guess. comments?

Comment: You stated that you wanted the foreign key on the `custom_time_fields` table instead of on the `time_logs` table. You _would_ have to switch the `belongs_to` and `has_one` declarations on your models if you want that. Functionally, it doesn't matter; you can use `:dependent => :destroy` either way.

Comment: The validation link 404s. Also curious if it's documented anywhere that the `has_one` relation is effectively a "has zero or one" relation. I did find that [`has_many` means "has zero or more"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association).